# How to correctly change the content of a DataViewModel

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

wxPython is giving me a lot of headaches lately, so I once again have to ask you guys here :)

## My Setup

- Windows 7
- Portable Python v 2.7.6.1 (http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython2.7.6.1/)
- wxPython 3.0.2.0 (http://www.wxpython.org/)

The given code is a very boiled down version of my actual app. Actually, I have one big model, that is displayed in different controls in different manners.
Therefore, I have this one model, which is the `modelRoot` in the code example, from which I build different DataViewModels (`MyDvcModel`) for different DataViewCtrls. In the code example, I only have one DataViewModel and one DataViewCtrl, because it suffices to show my problem.
I tried to stick close to the DataViewModel example in https://github.com/svn2github/wxPython/blob/master/trunk/demo/DVC_DataViewModel.py

## The Code

This is my minimal working example:

```
import wx
import wx.dataview
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

#class for a single item
class DvcTreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, value='item'):
        self.parent   = None
        self.children = []
        self.value    = value

    def AddChild(self, dvcTreeItem):
        self.children.append(dvcTreeItem)
        dvcTreeItem.parent = self

    def RemoveChild(self, dvcTreeItem):
        self.children.remove(dvcTreeItem)
        dvcTreeItem.parent = None

#class for the model
class MyDvcModel(wx.dataview.PyDataViewModel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        wx.dataview.PyDataViewModel.__init__(self)
        self.root = root
        pub.subscribe(self.OnItemAdded, 'ITEM_ADDED')

    #-------------------- REQUIRED FUNCTIONS -----------------------------
    def GetColumnCount(self):
        return 1
    def GetChildren(self, item, children):
        if not item:
            children.append(self.ObjectToItem(self.root))
            return 1
        else:
            objct = self.ItemToObject(item)
            for child in objct.children:
                #print "GetChildren called. Items returned = " + str([child.value for child in objct.children])
                children.append(self.ObjectToItem(child))
            return len(objct.children)
    def IsContainer(self, item):
        if not item:
            return True
        else:
            return (len(self.ItemToObject(item).children) != 0)
        return False
    def GetParent(self, item):
        if not item:
            return wx.dataview.NullDataViewItem
        parentObj = self.ItemToObject(item).parent
        if parentObj is None:
            return wx.dataview.NullDataViewItem
        else:
            return self.ObjectToItem(parentObj)
    def GetValue(self, item, col):
        if not item:
            return None
        else:
            return self.ItemToObject(item).value

    #-------------------- CUSTOM FUNCTIONS -----------------------------
    def OnItemAdded(self, obj):
        self.Update(obj) #for some weird reason, the update function cannot be used directly as event handler for pub (?).

    def Update(self, obj, currentItem=wx.dataview.DataViewItem()):
        children = []
        self.GetChildren(currentItem, children)
        for child in children:
            self.Update(obj, child) #recursively step through the tree to find the item that belongs to the added object
            if self.ItemToObject(child) == obj:
                self.ItemAdded(self.GetParent(child), child)
                print "item " + obj.value + " was added!"
                break

#class for the frame
class wxTreeAddMini(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_3DLIGHT))
        self.myDVC = wx.dataview.DataViewCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.myButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add Child", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.myDelButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Del Child", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        mySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mySizer.Add(self.myDVC, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mySizer.Add(self.myButton, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mySizer.Add(self.myDelButton, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mySizer)

app = wx.App(False)
modelRoot = DvcTreeItem('root')
child1 = DvcTreeItem('child1 - the forgotten one')
child1.AddChild(DvcTreeItem('even complete subtrees'))
child1.AddChild(DvcTreeItem('disappear'))
modelRoot.AddChild(child1)
modelRoot.AddChild(DvcTreeItem('child2 - the forgotten brother'))
childNum = 3
model = MyDvcModel(modelRoot)
frame = wxTreeAddMini(None)
frame.myDVC.AssociateModel(model)
frame.myDVC.AppendTextColumn("stuff", 0, width=250, mode=wx.dataview.DATAVIEW_CELL_INERT)
frame.Show()

def DeleteLastItemFromRoot(*ignoreEvent):
    global childNum
    if modelRoot.children != []:
        obj = modelRoot.children[-1] #select last item
        modelRoot.RemoveChild(obj)
        model.ItemDeleted(model.ObjectToItem(modelRoot), model.ObjectToItem(obj))

def AddItemToRoot(*ignoreEvent):
    global childNum
    newObject = DvcTreeItem('child' + str(childNum))
    modelRoot.AddChild(newObject)
    childNum += 1
    VARIANT = 'callItemAdded'
    if VARIANT == 'viaMessage':
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'ITEM_ADDED', obj=newObject)
    elif VARIANT == 'callItemAdded':
        model.ItemAdded(model.ObjectToItem(modelRoot), model.ObjectToItem(newObject))

frame.myButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, AddItemToRoot)
frame.myDelButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, DeleteLastItemFromRoot)
app.MainLoop()
```

## My Goal

My ultimate goal is to only update the low level model (`modelRoot` and its descendants/children) and have all DataViewModels being updated by that. Unfortunately, I have to call `ItemAdded` on each model, which is a pretty big pain (cause I have to do the same for deleting, editing and moving items).
Also, I don't know the item ID of the newly added object, because the item ID is different in each DataViewModel. Therefore, I use pub to send a message to all the DataViewModels, which then search for that new object and call `ItemAdded` on themselves respectively.
Since this didn't work out properly, I tried to call `ItemAdded` directly, which also doesn't work.
You can switch between both implementations by changing the value of the `VARIANT` variable. The final goal is to get the VARIANT `'viaMessage'` to work.

## The Problem

Here is a description of how to reproduce the weird behavior:

1. Start the application. You should only see the collapsed root item (with the '+' next to it). Without touching the tree view, just click the "Add Children" button a few times.
2. Now expand the root item. You will see that there are a few children in it (as many as how often you clicked). However, at program start, two **children** were added, which are now **missing**. *This is not desired and I consider this wrong behavior.*
   [image: Screenshot of wrong behavior]

   - **EDIT**: Okay, things got even weirder:
     I edited the code and implemented an additional delete button. When I repeat everything until step 2. and then delete all the added children, the children 1 and 2 suddenly magically appear again! (left after adding 2 children, then expanding root || right after deleting the two added children and expanding root again)
     [image: Screenshot of wrong behavior with Del button][image: Screenshot of weird behavior after deleting added children]
3. Anyway, now please restart the application (close the window and run the script again). Now expand the root item and click "Add Children". *Wow, suddenly it works.*
   [image: Screenshot of correct behavior]
4. Okay, let's try another one: Restart the application. Expand and collapse the root item again. Now click "Add Children" a few times. Now expand the root item again.

Again, it seemed to work. All children, the ones that were added at the beginning as well as the ones added by the button are there.

*So the bug apparently only appears when children are added before you have ever expanded the parent item.*

What kind of sorcery is this?

My impression is that what I want to achieve is nothing extraordinary and I'm wondering where the mistake is and that I can't find that problem via google, so I have to assume that the mistake is on my side, but I can't find it.

Only to justify the title of this question: I have similar problems when deleting an item. So, the question is more generally about how to correctly change the content of a DataViewModel (e.g. delete, add and change the value of an item) rather than just adding an item.

## My Attempts

- I tried to google for `"wxwidgets dataviewmodel itemadded collapsed"`, but the results are not what I'm looking for.
- I have an idea, which I haven't tried so far, because it would only be a workaround: On program start, I could once programmatically expand and collapse all subtrees. However, I would like to avoid that workaround.
- I tried to debug it but couldn't see anything suspicious.
- I checked the original wxWidgets code but didn't quite grasp it.

## My Questions

- **What is wrong? Why doesn't it work as desired? Is this a wxPython bug or a bug in my code?**
- **How can I fix it?**

#### Side-Quests

- I there a better way to achieve my goal than how I have implemented it?
- Do you see any other flaws or drawbacks in my code? (except that it's a slimmed down version and I tried to avoid boilerplate as `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` and MVC design (at least C is missing) etc.)
- Why can't I use `MyDvcModel.Update` as message handler directly but I have to use the indirection via `OnItemAdded()`? If I use `MyDvcModel.Update`, I get an exception before the app actually starts `(TypeError: in method 'DataViewItem___cmp__', expected argument 2 of type 'wxDataViewItem *')`.

Would be nice, if these questions could also be answered, but it's neither necessary nor sufficient for me to accept your answer as solution ;)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `PyDataViewModel` code is more complicated than required for your application. Instead of `Update`ing your DVC model it is perfectly possible to just clear it (making the model itself figuring out how data has changed and sending messages to the DVCs depending on it). This works without noticeable delay for hundred items (i have not tested with several thousands).

Do as follows:

```
    # remove subscription, no longer needed
    # pub.subscribe(self.OnItemAdded, 'ITEM_ADDED')

    # remove OnItemAdded and Update
    #-------------------- CUSTOM FUNCTIONS -----------------------------
```

Simplify to:

```
def DeleteLastItemFromRoot(*ignoreEvent):
    global childNum
    if modelRoot.children != []:
        obj = modelRoot.children[-1] #select last item
        modelRoot.RemoveChild(obj)
        # no longer required, handled my model.Cleared() 
        # model.ItemDeleted(model.ObjectToItem(modelRoot), model.ObjectToItem(obj))
        # Forcing a synchronisation python model/PyDataViewModel/DVC
        model.Cleared()

def AddItemToRoot(*ignoreEvent):
    global childNum
    newObject = DvcTreeItem('child' + str(childNum))
    modelRoot.AddChild(newObject)
    childNum += 1
    # syncing
    model.Cleared()
```

Comment: Very nice tip! I was wondering, why wxPython wouldn't provide such a functionality. However, I didn't expect this functionality to be in a function called `Cleared`. Anyway, since the model is now correctly updated: Do you know how I can prevent `model.Cleared()` from recursively collapsing the whole tree (including all sub trees)?

Comment: I suppose the items are all collapsed because they are created anew on ``Cleared()``. This would be an interesting topic on its own: Will the ``IsExpanded`` state of an item be persisted when using the ``ItemAdded``/``ItemDeleted`` methods? I solved this by having the information for ``IsExpanded`` stored in the model itself (because this info was important in the realm of the model). When updating, I used ``mydvc.Freeze()``, ``model.Cleared()``, iterated over the interesting objects in the model, object to item, ``mydvc.Collapse/Expand(myitem)``, ``mydvc.Thaw()``.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, the `IsExpanded` state will be persistent when using `ItemAdded` and `ItemDeleted`, apart from the strange behavior described in this thread ;). I think I will stick to your suggestion and `Expand` the new nodes manually after remembering their state before calling `model.Cleared()`. Until I have time for that, I'll just live with the collapsed tree. Anyway, thanks for your input. Although it doesn't answer the question about what is actually going wrong, you have helped me a lot with this issue!

Comment: To answer the question what is wrong I would have to dig deeper (I smell something fishy in ``Update(...)`` but cannot put my finger on it yet).